# How do I change the size of the Header Menu DIV using CSS?

Tags: menu, header, size

What code do I add/ replace/ remove to change the size of[marketbot.net](http://marketbot.net)

Answer (score 0):

```
 #header {
            background: #FFFFFF
            width: 100%;
            padding: 30px 0px;
            position:relative;
            margin-top: 80px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
```

i didn't completely understand your question but i have tried to answer it.

you would need to edit

```
 #header {
        background: #FFFFFF
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px 0px;
    }
```

Comment: sorry to say this but i can't tell you this as i have not seen your style sheet could your post you style sheet.

Comment: there's one problem don't know the size you would like to change it to

Comment: #header {
            background: #FFFFFF
            width: 100%;
            padding: 30px 0px;
            position:relative;
            margin-top: 80px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        } 
        
        #header {
        background: #FFFFFF
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px 0px;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the global navigation menu or the slider that is on the page? The slider looks like it has a margin problem (in both I.E. 8 and Google Chrome).

I adjusted the css class named content-top to the following, so it isn't overflowing into the header:

```
.content-top
{
  position:relative;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

After I made the adjustments, it looks somewhat cleaner in the slider and header divs.

Comment: I did just that and my site ended up like this: marketbot.net

Comment: It looks like your adjusted a different class, in addition to the one I pointed out, and removed the background. The code I posted did not have any background attributes associated to it...